# SQl import BCP error

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I'm working on importing tables to sql server using BCP command with dat and xml file of tables.Here is my command:

```
-bcp database_name.dbo.TasksXml in task_xml.dat -T -f
task_xml.xml
```

But the BCP copy failed.The error am getting is:-

```
Starting copy...
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 1000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 2000
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]String data, right       truncation
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 3000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 4000
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 5000
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]String data, right  truncation
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 6000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 7000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 8000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 9000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 10000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 11000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 12000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 13000
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 14000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 15000
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 16000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 17000
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation 
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 18000
   1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 19000
   SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]String data, right   truncation
    1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 20000
    1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 21000
    SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
    Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]String data, right  truncation
    SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
    Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Text column data    incomplete
    SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 9420 
    Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]XML parsing: line
    1, character 1725, illegal xml character
```

BCP copy in failed.How can I solve this error? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

check the destination table database_name.dbo.TasksXml columns are adequate to handle your data, ideally they will match the original location you extracted the data from.